# How to share ngrx state between lazy loaded modules, can we have a shared module to do so?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx, modularization

Want to implement shared store module for sharing state between 2 feature modules
Can some one please share stackblitz or git repo link for shared state module

Comment: I would recommend to have them as a `rootStore` in the `AppModule` directly,

Comment: I am in the process of modularizing the application by having lazy routes and  separate feature stores. But we have multiple scenarios where one feature has some state dependency on other feature..so if i keep shared state in the rootStore in appModule , wouldn't it have a performance impact?

Comment: okay! make sense. so you want to share store between 2 or more features stores is that. So I would recommend to create a shared module between these features and put your store in it

Answer (score 0):

the store is accessible by all imported modules of a module that imports `StoreModule.forRoot`.

Therefore if you have `StoreModule.forRoot` in your `AppModule`, then any lazyloaded module can perform `this.store.select(SELECTOR)` or `this.store.dispatch(ACTION)` and it will return data and cause changes as you expect.